# Django - FileField set upload_to dynamically

Tags: python, django

For example i have to django apps

```
- project
-- photo 
-- attachments
```

And i create model where i keep my tmp files

```
# python 3.4
class UploadedFiles(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d')
```

But i want use this table for all uplaoded files and change `upload_to` dynamically.

I thought about it and wrote it

```
# python 3.4
def get_path(instance, filename):
    filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    return instance.path.format(filename, file_ext)


class UploadedFiles(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path, blank=True)
```

So, at first i create new entry

```
# python 3.4
uf = UploadedFiles.path = 'attachments/%Y/%m/%d/{0}.blabla.{1}'
uf.save()
```

At next i save file

```
uf.file = file
uf.save()
```

Ok. Its works but looks very bad. How i can do it normally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
from django.core.files import File, ContentFile

uf = UploadedFiles(path='...', file=File(fp))
# Or
uf = UploadedFiles(path='...', file=ContentFile(file_content))
uf.save()
```

Furthermore, `'%Y'` does not work if you specify `upload_to` as a function, if I remember right.

Comment: I want upload file with my `upload_to` without creating `path`.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev You mean giving path a default value: `path = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='attachments/...')`?

Comment: No... For example, i have table where i keep all my files. I want keep files in different folders, i want set `upload_to` param dinamiclly as in example, but without `path` method in my model.

Comment: @AlexKiselev Sorry I don't get it. But you have to implement an `upload_to` to dynamically generate paths.